# start /wait with VeraCrypt Format.exe does not wait until VeraCrypt Format exits

Tags: file, batch-file, encryption

I have a batch project with this one line of code that does not seem to work. Here is the sample code:

```
@echo off
start /wait System\Engine\InfusedApps\BatchOS.OS.Encryption.x64.x86.free.executable\"VeraCrypt Format.exe" /create OS /password uZhPPGzELNyWLrz3pbC8NFgB /hash whirlpool /encryption AES(Twofish(Serpent)) /filesystem NTFS /size 10G /force
echo part one done
pause
cls
start /wait System\Engine\InfusedApps\BatchOS.OS.Encryption.x64.x86.free.executable\VeraCrypt.exe /q /s /v OS.hc /l Y /p uZhPPGzELNyWLrz3pbC8NFgB
echo part two done
```

"Part one done" gets echoed before the `VeraCrypt Format.exe` app terminates. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: do you need windows popping? If not you could try changing `start /wait` by `cmd /c` to force program to wait for end

Comment: Do you know what the name of the process is (when viewed from taskmanager or cmd) if so there's a way to do it by checking if the process is running or not

Comment: Yes, I tired cmd /c function, but the code still continues before I get the message, "The VeraCrypt Volume has been created successfully."

Comment: Just use the executable by itself.